# Client certificate authentication and CA certificate in Azure

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-roles, client-certificates

I need to authenticate requests to Azure Cloud Service **Web Role** using client certificates. How to put the **Certification Authority (CA) root certificate** in a right trusted store?

I tried to upload it in Management Portal and then defining it in service definition file with **AuthRoot** store name:

```
<Certificate name="RootCA" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="AuthRoot" />
```

What's really strange is that it works... but only sometimes. It may work after an instance reboot, but may not work after a service update or another instance reboot. It seems like a bug in Azure.

When I say "works" I mean server successfully accepts the client certificate and processes the request.
When I say "doesn't work" I mean server doesn't negotiate a connection after certificate checks and "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." exception is thrown on a client side.

**How to make it working stable?**

**UPD:**

Found this record in System Windows Event Log (source is Schannel):

> When asking for client authentication, this server sends a list of
>   trusted certificate authorities to the client. The client uses this
>   list to choose a client certificate that is trusted by the server.
>   Currently, this server trusts so many certificate authorities that the
>   list has grown too long. This list has thus been truncated. The
>   administrator of this machine should review the certificate
>   authorities trusted for client authentication and remove those that do
>   not really need to be trusted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact problem is described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801679.

After December 2012 Windows update a lot of certificates were added to AuthRoot store. So we have to remove them to solve the problem.

To make it I use PowerShell startup task:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot\Certificates | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*\<YOUR_CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT>"} | Remove-Item
```

To run it from CMD startup task:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\Startup.ps1
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

And in ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<WebRole name="Web">
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
  </Startup>
  <!-- ... ->
</WebRole>
```